# Expected Value of Placards

Tags: markov-chains

Let us say we have 10 placards with numbers from (-5 to 5 excluding zero) laid in a circular fashion.  In each round, you perform a swap such that you switch the position of two adjacent placards . Find the expected number of swaps such that no two adjacent placards sum to zero.

I am looking for translating this into a markov chain, could someone give me an idea?

Comment: What is the starting position? Is it $-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ or $-5, 5, -4, 4, -3, 3, -2, 2, -1, 1$?

Comment: It is randomly arranged at the beginning

Comment: I presume the swaps are also uniformly random? This looks pretty complicated; the chain will have lots of inequivalent states. Where did you encounter this problem? Is it perhaps meant to be solved with a computer?

Comment: This problem was inspired to mimic an contest problem from HMMT 2023 Feb.  I wanted to reframe the ask in the question into something measurable. https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2023/feb/guts/problems.pdf - Problem 30

Comment: @Satish Ramanathan I'm sure the swaps in that HMMT problem are *not* intended to be random.  If $\ S(C)\ $ is the  *minimum* number of swaps needed to separate all the adjacent pairs of twins in a given configuration $\ C\ $, there's a nifty way  of determining the value of $\ S(C)\ $ for any $\ C\ $. The question is asking for the expected value of $\ S(C)\ $ when $\ C\ $ is chosen uniformly at random. Determining it is an exercise in the use of linearity of expectations.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera, I agree that i might have not understood the "minimum number of swaps" into the reading of the ask in the problem.

Comment: Given a sequence of coin flips, such as ‘HTTHTHT...’, we define an inversion as a switch from
H to T or T to H. For instance, the sequence ‘HTTHT’ has 3 inversions.
Harrison has a weighted coin that lands on heads 2/3 of the time and tails 1/3
of the time. If Harrison flips the coin 10 times, what is the expected number of inversions in the sequence of flips - Answer: $\sum_{p=1}^{9}\sum_{i=0}^{10} p(2/3)^i (1/3)^(10-i)(\binom{i-1} {p})(\binom {11-i} {(i-p)})=4$